# Module has no attribute "_USE_C_DESCRIPTORS" error by mypy when trying to import a Protobuf module

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers, mypy, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I have created a simple Protobuf object (let's call it `file_nam.proto`) like the one below:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package something.somethingelse;

message SomeName {
  string first = 1;
  string second = 2;
  string third = 3;
  string forth = 4;
  uint64 fifth = 5;
  uint64 sixth = 6;
}
```

which I then successfully compile into .py file using protobuf package. The issue is that when I try to import the `.py` module in another module, `mypy` returns the following error when I run the `pre-commit` command.

```
interfaces/proto/file_name_pb2.py:28: error: Module has no attribute "_USE_C_DESCRIPTORS"
```

the error refers to the last line in

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: rasv2_task.proto
"""Generated protocol buffer code."""
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pool as _descriptor_pool
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
.
.
.

if _descriptor._USE_C_DESCRIPTORS == False:
    .
    .
    .
```

but it doesn't make any sense because `_descriptor` does, in fact, have a _USE_C_DESCRIPTORS attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mypy does not understand the generated code from protobuf -- it does some meta-programmery things that confuse the type checker

but fortunately there's a project to generate `.pyi` stubs that mypy can understand -- https://github.com/nipunn1313/mypy-protobuf

mypy will prefer the `.pyi` files to the real `.py` files and you'll be able to use those types elsewhere

Comment: it worked elegantly!! thanks